# How to print ASCII table as a table

Tags: c++, ascii

I have a project to print ascii table from 0-32 with words and from 32-256 with characters with table.
[image]

What I did is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout<<"0 NUL"<<endl;
 cout<<"1 Start of Header"<<endl;
................
cout<<"32 Space"<<endl;

   char a;
    int i;

    for (int i=33; i<256; i++){
    a=i;
    cout << i << " " << a << " " <<endl;
    
    
    } 
return 0;
}

the output is:
32 Space
33 !
34 "
35 #
36 $
37 %
38 &
39 '
40 (
.....
```

I want it in a table with rows just like in table.
The output should be like
000 nul            33 !                  66 B

Comment: Won't be writing any code for you, but here are some ideas. For ascii 0-32, you could store an array of `const char*` with the names of the characters. E.g. `const char* names[33] = {"NUL", "Start Of Header", ..., "Space"};`. For 33-256, simply printing out the char representation is probably good enough.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want it in a table like the photo."? Do you want the console output formatted as an ASCII table or do you want to produce an image?

Comment: Why are 16, 17, 18, 19 marked as "frei"?  All values in ASCII are labeled.  Your job is to find them all.

Comment: BTW, leading zeros in C and C++ parlance mean that the number is octal.  I recommend not prefixing with zeros.

Answer (score 3):

> I want it in a table like the photo. Can any one help with the code?

If you want to print a table with more than one item per row, you should probably print more than one item per line, right?

Do you see any patterns in your table? The first row is 000, 033, 066...; the second row is 001, 034, 067... How would you print one of those lines? How would you print the next line?

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to make it in a table with more than 1 item per row but can find the right code any help?

Comment: Look at the line in your code where you print a line. See how you print `i` and `a` and `endl`? You *could* print `i`, `a`, and then other variables representing another item, say `j` and `b`, `k` and `c`, etc. Or, since you know the relationship between the different columns, you could just calculate the other values based on `i`, e.g. `i+32`, `a+32`, etc.

Comment: You might have an easier time if you start by printing the table with just two columns. If you can do that, it should be easy to change it to use 3 columns, 4 columns, etc.